# How to pivot row-wise info to column wise flags in R or sci-kit learn in a data set from MS SQL?

Tags: python, sql-server, r, scikit-learn, dataset

I am attempting to see if there is a better paradigm to generate the data set that we will be using for a data science exercise. My colleagues will be consuming a member time series with a large amount of flags as indicated below and since the number of items is in the hundreds and likely to grow I am wondering if the community is aware of a better way to query out these types of flags for consumption in R or scikit-learn.

I can continue to generate the SQL statements using SQL itself (get the case statements by querying all the items available) and running these statements, but I am starting to think that a more slick solution may exist on the analytic front that I can propose to my colleagues.  Also the max columns in a MS SQL database is capped at 1,024 for non-wide and 30,000 for wide so at some point this paradigm simply fails.

What they have requested for analysis:

```
    select 
    a.member,a.timewindow
    ,max(case when [member has item 1 test here] then 1 else 0 end) as hasItem1
    ,max(case when [member has item 2 test here] then 1 else 0 end) as hasItem2
...
    ,max(case when [member has item N test here] then 1 else 0 end) as hasItemN

    ,max(case when [member has status 1 test here] then 1 else 0 end) as hasStatus1
    ,max(case when [member has status 2 test here] then 1 else 0 end) as hasStatus2
...
    ,max(case when [member has status N test here] then 1 else 0 end) as hasStatusN
    from 
        (
        [massive join w/ granular member time lined information ]) a
    group by
    a.member,a.timewindow
```

What seems optimal to share with them, but will need to suggest how to handle on their end in R/python(scikit-learn):

```
    select 
    a.member,a.timewindow
    ,try_convert(varchar(100),itemType)) as Info
    from 
        (
        [massive join w/ granular member time lined information ]) a
    group by
    a.member,a.timewindow,try_convert(varchar(100),itemType))
    UNION
    select 
    a.member,a.timewindow
    ,try_convert(varchar(100),StatusType)) as Info
    from 
        (
        [massive join w/ granular member time lined information ]) a
    group by
    a.member,a.timewindow,try_convert(varchar(100),StatusType))
```

Does anyone have ideas what they should be using to work with this type of data set to draw inferences?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pypyodbc?

First make connection

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MyServer;UID=ronjeremi;PWD=password;DATABASE=db")
```

You can read more [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pypyodbc/)

Comment: Right that is a method to connect... I am attempting to figure out if there are methods to not have hundreds of flag statements output to separate columns and if row wise methods are known to exist so I can suggest these instead.